# Manual enrollments and expiration time

Tags: moodle

On Moodle documentation for Manual Enrollments, one can see:

Enrolment expiration action - specifies what happens when user enrolments reach expiration date. Please note that option "Unenrol user from course" purges grades, group memberships, preferences and other user related data from the courses

and

Default enrolment duration - this sets the default length of enrolment in new courses.

From what I can understand, if I enroll a user in a course with Manual Enrollment, and if I have set the default enrolment duration to 10 minutes and the expiration action to unenrol, the user that I have enroled with this plugin will no longer belong in a course after 10 minutes (provided that the cron server has run).

But, the user is not removed from the course and I have checked that the cron server is running.

My moodle version is 2.4.1, and I'm wondering if I'm the only one that has noticed this and if it is working in any other version...

Thanks

Comment: This may only apply to newly enrolled users since you made the change to `unenrol user from course`.  Users that were setup before you set the default to unenrol may not be affected.

Comment: Have also a look on `expiredaction`, in `Site administration → Plugins → Enrolments → Manual enrolments`. The default action keeps the users enrolled.

Answer (score 0):

You are right but I want to add something here, as you told cron server has to run to complete unenrolment process, but Moodle also check user accessibility during accessing course by that user, user is prevented to access course if his enrollment duration has been over but grade of user remain in the course unless cron not run for that.

One interesting case also discovered by me if we allowed guest access in the course then it will not work as I mentioned earlier user will get complete access of course even his enrollment duration is over.